# logout function not working properly.It works after clicking 3 to 4 times.Initially it just reloads the page but does not logout

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security

i created a angular 2 and spring security application.
After logging in ,when i try to logout it does not logout.
After trying 3-4 times it logs out.

Even the "OPTIONS" pre flight call does not appear in network tab.

The login part works perfectly.
Let me know if any other code part is required.

Below is my angular service code.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginService } from '../login.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  loggedIn: boolean;

    constructor(private loginService: LoginService, private router : Router) {
        if(localStorage.getItem('PortalAdminHasLoggedIn') == '') {
            this.loggedIn = false;
        } else {
            this.loggedIn = true;
        }
    }

    logout(){
        this.loginService.logout().subscribe(
            res => {
                console.log("logout  clicked inside res");
                localStorage.setItem('PortalAdminHasLoggedIn', '');
            },
            err => console.log(err)
            );
            console.log("logout  clicked before reload");
        location.reload();
        console.log("logout  clicked before reload");
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }

    getDisplay() {
    if(!this.loggedIn){
      return "none";
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Below Spring application code.

```
package com.userFront.config;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class RequestFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

        if (!(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS"))) {
            try {
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Pre-flight");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,DELETE");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "authorization, content-type," +
                    "access-control-request-headers,access-control-request-method,accept,origin,authorization,x-requested-with");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        }

    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}

}






package com.userFront.config;

import java.security.SecureRandom;

import org.hibernate.cfg.Environment;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConstructorBinding;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import com.userFront.service.serviceImpl.UserSecurityService;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
    @Autowired
    private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;
    
    private static final String SALT="salt";
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12, new SecureRandom(SALT.getBytes()));
    }
     
    
    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS= {
            "/webjars/**",
            "/css/**",
            "/js/**",
            "/images/**",
            "/",
            "/about/**",
            "/contact/**",
            "/error/**/**",
            "/console/**",
            "/signup"
    };
    
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
        
        http.csrf().disable()
            .cors().disable()
            .formLogin().failureUrl("/index?error").defaultSuccessUrl("/userFront").loginPage("/index").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/index?logout")
            .deleteCookies("remember-me").permitAll()
            .and()
            .rememberMe();
            
        
    }
    
    
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userSecurityService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on here: (it reloads the page and navigats to login, before waiting for logout response.)

```
logout() {
    this.loginService.logout().subscribe(
        res => {
            console.log("logout  clicked inside res");
            localStorage.setItem('PortalAdminHasLoggedIn', '');
        },
        err => console.log(err)
    );
    console.log("logout  clicked before reload");
    location.reload();
    console.log("logout  clicked before reload");
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}
```

when you subscribe to result of logout method, you should wait for it to get the result (it's asynchronous.). So change it to:

```
logout() {
    this.loginService.logout().subscribe(
        res => {
            console.log("logout  clicked inside res");
            localStorage.setItem('PortalAdminHasLoggedIn', '');
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            location.reload();
        },
        err => console.log(err)
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked.
I added the below code.Also i had to add location.reload()
Does router.navigate not reload the page?


this.loginService.logout().subscribe(
   res => {
    console.log("logout  clicked inside res");
    localStorage.setItem('PortalAdminHasLoggedIn', '');
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    location.reload();
   },
   err => console.log(err)
   );

Comment: @wolf no problem. yes the `navigate` will do in-app navigate without any reload. i thought you're reloading for testing purpose. (updated the answer). i think it's ok to reload the page if you want.